# HTML5 - video capture - QR code scanning - how can I start auto focus?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

When using the Html-5 <video> tag, I try to capture QR-code texts.

When scanning a QR-picture I see that the QR-picture stays vague. No auto focus whatever. Even after 1 minute.

How can I add auto focus for the  recording / capturing?

This is the code:

```
<video id="preview" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></video>
```

The capturing is done via a Javascript library InstaScan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating a number of free Javascript libraries for QR scanning (using a video) I did not find a very good QR scanner.

Today I did an experiment with creating an Ionic QR scanner. The quality of this (Cordova) QR scanner is very, very good.

Auto-focus is working fine.

I hoped to create a Progressive Web App that was using a Javascript QR scanner in combination with `<video>`. Alas.